# Math "sitting on same line" as text?

Tags: amsmath

I don't know how to describe my question, but how might I be able to make the "lim" sit even with the text surrounding it? See image below.

I would like the "lim" to sit on the red line that I have added in. This is a minor thing that is really bugging me. I am using the "aligned" environment as in the following code:

```
Evaluate \begin{aligned}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{x}\end{aligned}.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{x}$.` ?

Comment: Wow, that seems to do the trick, and a lot nicer than `aligned`. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @marmot -- make that an answer.  this question deserves to stick around, which isn't guaranteed if it's closed as "fixed in comments".

Comment: `aligned` is meant for setting multiline components.  a fraction, regardless of having more than one visual level, is conceptually just a single line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : done. I'm actually wondering how @clocktower got her or his first line, in which all expressions ``sit on the same line''.

Answer (score 10):

In-text equations can (and probably always should) be bounded by `$` symbols. That is, you get the desired alignment with

```
 Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{x}$.
```

Comment: er, um, ... `aligned` does accomplish horizontal alignment, but on multiple lines (the vertical component), not just one line.